# Android - Navigation Drawer is shown only in one activity c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, navigation

I have implemented a Navigation Drawer in my c# Android app, I did the same as this project in [github](https://github.com/suchithm/NavigationDrawerMD). The problem is that the Navigation is only showing in one activity, then if I tried to start another activity from the Navigation, it disappears. I want after the launch of the activity, the Navigation Drawer to stay like the case in MasterPage in ASP.NET and not disappear.
That's what I have tried to do in order to show the Drawer in my second activity which is launched on Navigation Drawer item click :

```
public class SecondActivity: NavActivity // extending from the NavActivity where the Navigation drawer is implemented
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View contentView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.portfolio_layout, null, false);
        drawerLayout.AddView(contentView, 0);
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Home selected!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

But the `SecondActivity` code are compiled successfully I know that because the `Toast message` is showing.

Answer (score 1):

A navigation drawer works with one activity and multiple fragments. Take a look at the [Android training](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer) to get a deeper understanding how it is used and come back if you have more questions.

Comment: Should I turn my Activity to a Fragment ?

Comment: You basically need two fragments and one activity.